# Yii CListView: how to disable all additional html

Tags: yii

Im trying to generate RSS page with CListView but i got additional generated html in my results:

```
<div id="yw0" class="list-view">
<div class="items">
```

and

```
<div class="keys" style="display:none" title="/index.php/rss"><span>2383</span><span>4743</span><span>1421</span></div>
```

How can i remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without changing CListView class (yii v.1.1.8).

CListView extends CBaseListView
http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.8/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php

```
    /**
     * Renders the view.
     * This is the main entry of the whole view rendering.
     * Child classes should mainly override {@link renderContent} method.
     */
    public function run()
    {
            $this->registerClientScript();

            echo CHtml::openTag($this->tagName,$this->htmlOptions)."\n";

            $this->renderContent();
            $this->renderKeys();

            echo CHtml::closeTag($this->tagName);
    }

    /**
     * Renders the key values of the data in a hidden tag.
     */
    public function renderKeys()
    {
            echo CHtml::openTag('div',array(
                    'class'=>'keys',
                    'style'=>'display:none',
                    'title'=>Yii::app()->getRequest()->getUrl(),
            ));
            foreach($this->dataProvider->getKeys() as $key)
                    echo "<span>".CHtml::encode($key)."</span>";
            echo "</div>\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

actually it is quite simple, only a few lines of code.

INSTEAD of using CListView, just use its guts:

```
$data = $dataProvider->getData();
foreach($data as $i => $item)
  Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('your_item_view',
    array('index' => $i, 'data' => $item, 'widget' => $this));
```

that's it.

Comment: Both answers are correct.. The accepted one is better if you need a custom list view to be used over and over again. This answer works great for those one off situations.

Comment: But this make the pagination automatic?

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good wiki tutorial on Yii site about [generating Feeds](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/20/how-to-generate-web-feed-for-an-application/). CListView is intended to display an html list of items, not feed of any kind.